# How can I instantiate a sub class by passing a base class to sub class's `__init__()`?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

This might be indicative of poor design, but I'm wondering how to do it or how else I should achieve this.

I want to make a class, `FalseAlias`, which is inherited from the base class `Alias`, but the args for each are different. I want to fill in all the member variables of `Alias` by passing an instance of `Alias` to `FalseAlias`, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

```py
class Alias:
    '''A class to contain information about strings in SQL files.'''
    def __init__(self, regex_match):
        self.txt = regex_match.group()
        self.span = regex_match.span()
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.txt

    
class FalseAlias(Alias):
    '''A class for alias strings which are false positives from RegEx matching.'''
    def __init__(self, alias, reason_string):
        # this is not the correct approach, 
        #    it would only work if I have `regex_match` to pass through `FalseAlias`
        # Alias.__init__(alias)  # can't give regex match as arg, not available
        self.reason = reason_string
```

Really all I want to do is attach extra information to the subclass `FalseAlias`, i.e. `reason_string`, which is inappropriate for the base class to contain. My object-oriented programming skills are elementary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is FalseAlias different from FakeAlias?

Comment: `self.txt = alias.txt; self.span = alias.span`?

Comment: Are you sure you want subclassing? If `FalseAlias` receives an `Alias` as an argument, it sounds it should be a container, not a subclass.

Comment: @khelwood good catch! i haven't decided on a name

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that totally works. i just see a maintainability issue if i start modifying and adding member variables

Comment: @Barmar I'll have to go research what that means

Comment: @JustinMai you can do something like `vars(self).update(vars(alias))` But generally I would just go wit the more explicit approach. Or just not use inheritance at all.

Comment: You could also make the base class explicitly define a list of attribute names the subclass must override — explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 1):

Passing an instance of a base class to a subclass's constructor doesn't make much sense. It seems like you're not familiar with subclassing at all, and actually you want to *extend* `Alias`'s init method. Consider this:

```
class FalseAlias(Alias):

    def __init__(self, regex_match, reason_string):
        super().__init__(regex_match)  # Call "Alias.__init__" and use it to set attrs
        self.reason = reason_string

false_alias = FalseAlias(re.search('x', 'sox'), 'some reason')
print(vars(false_alias))  # Show all instance attrs
# -> {'txt': 'x', 'span': (2, 3), 'reason': 'some reason'}
```

---

Otherwise, it seems like you want a container, not a subclass, as Barmar [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63929098/how-can-i-instantiate-a-sub-class-by-passing-a-base-class-to-sub-classs-init#comment113046818_63929098).

```
class FalseAlias:

    def __init__(self, alias, reason_string):
        self.alias = alias
        self.reason = reason_string

alias = Alias(re.search('x', 'sox'))
false_alias = FalseAlias(alias, 'some reason')
print(vars(false_alias))
# -> {'alias': x, 'reason': 'some reason'}
```

---

BTW, `Alias.__repr__` isn't useful, as you can see above. [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) has advice:

> If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form `<...some useful description...>` should be returned.

So for example:

```
def __repr__(self):
    r = '<{} object: {!r}, {!r}>'.format(
        type(self).__name__,
        self.txt,
        self.span,
        )
    return r
```

Running the above example again:

```
{'alias': <Alias object: 'x', (2, 3)>, 'reason': 'some reason'}
```